# How to apply a function to each element of matrix considering the neighbouring cells

Tags: r

I would like apply a function to each element of a matrix considering the upper, lower, left and right neighbouring cells:

```
a=1; b=3; c=8; d=2

m <- matrix(1:20, nrow=4, ncol=5)
mn <- matrix(NA, nrow=4, ncol=5)

for(i in 2:3){
  for(j in 2:4){
    mn[i,j] <- a*m[i-1,j]+b*m[i+1,j]+c*m[i,j-1]+d*m[i,j+1]
  }
}
```

Is there an alternative way using sapply or something else?

Comment: one minor simplification: `a <- c(1, 3, 8, 2)` at the top. Then, in the loop, `mn[i,j] <- sum(c(m[i-1,j], m[i+1,j], m[i,j-1], m[i,j+1]) * a)`.

Answer (score 0):

You can subset multiple rows and columns of a matrix, like this:

```
.i = 2:3
.j = 2:4

mn[.i,.j] = a*m[.i-1,.j] + b*m[.i+1,.j] + c*m[.i,.j-1] + d*m[.i,.j+1]


> mn
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
# [1,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
# [2,]   NA   62  118  174   NA
# [3,]   NA   76  132  188   NA
# [4,]   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA
```